# JavaScript function declaration, a colon in function declaration

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between function declaration `function test()` and `test: function()` in JavaScript?

```
function test() {
    …
}
```

vs.

```
test: function() {
    …
}
```

---

In the question «[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)» functions were declared like:

```
function test() {
    …
}
```

and

```
var test = function() {
    …
};
```

Which is a bit different from syntax perspective comparing to my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: The questions are not the same. It's not a dublicate

Comment: The second one is a syntax error. Couldn't you have tried that out yourself?

Comment: test: function() is not a syntax error. This function is declared inside the object. Tushar explained it well

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`function test()` is normal function declaration which you can call directly using function name. While `test: function()` is the function defined inside some object, so it has to be called using object on which it is defined.

**Example**

**Function Declaration**

```
function test() {
    alert('In Test');
}

test(); // Calling test
```

**Method**

```
var myObj = {
    test: function() {
        alert('Inside test');
    }
};

myObj.test(); // Calling test
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider this javascript object :

```
{ "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : "23"}
```

Javascript being weakly typed, you can replace "23" (string) with 23 (number) :

```
{ "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : 23}
```

No error, works perfectly.

Actually, you can replace 23 with anything else : a boolean

```
{ "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : true}
```

another object

```
{ "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : {"2014" : 22 , "2015": 23 } }
```

or even a function

```
{ "name" : "Joe",
  "age" : function(){ alert("23");} }
```

*Sidenote : some people hate Javascript for being so lax. Other people (like me) love Javascript for this very same reason, because this flexibility is its power (that and being asynchrounous).*

You can name that object "person" and ask for his name and age :

```
var person = { "name" : "Joe",
      "age" : function(){ alert("23");} }

console.log( person.name ); // will log "Joe"
person.age(); // "age" is a function, so you need to call it. It will alert 23.
```

Now you can create a function that will return that object :

```
function Person() {
    return{
      "name" : "Joe",

      "age" : function(){ alert("23");},

      sayHello : function() {
        alert("Hello");
      },

      sleep : function() {
        alert("I'm sleeping");
      }
    }
};

console.log( Person().name ); // logs "Joe"
Person().age(); // alerts "23"
Person().sayHello(); // alerts "Hello"
Person().sleep(); // alerts "I'm sleeping".
```

**`age`, `sayHello` and `sleep` are functions, that are called methods of the `Person` function.**

One usually avoids calling `Person()` multiple times, and create a `new Person` instead :

```
var person = new Person();
person.sayHello(); // alerts "Hello"
person.sleep(); // alerts "I'm sleeping".
```

This method allows to create many persons, by passing parameters :

```
function Person(name, age) {
    return{
        "name" : name,

        "age" : function(){ alert(age);},

        sayHello : function() { // sayHello or "sayHello", both work
          alert("Hello, my name is "+ this.name );
        },

        sleep : function() {
          alert("I'm sleeping");
        }
     }
};

var person = new Person("John", 25);
person.sayHello(); // alerts "Hello, my name is John"
person.age(); // alerts "25".
```

This method currently replace classes, that Javascript 5 (EcmaScript 5) lacks. But EcmaScript 6 will come soon, with proper classes.

Comment: it's a great intro to JS classes but it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There are three differences in the `test:function()` and `function test()`.

#### Calling:

`test:function()` will a function defined inside the object. So you will need it to call from that object.
`function test()` is a normal function you call call it using `test()`.
Consider this example.

```js
const obj = {
  insidefunc:function(){
    console.log("Inside");
  }
}
function test(){
  console.log("Outside");
}

obj.insidefunc(); //Inside
test(); //Outside

insidefunc(); //Uncaught ReferenceError: insidefunc is not defined
```

#### this Binding

In the `test:function()` `this` will refer to the the Object of which the function is property of.While in `function test()` `this` will refer to `window` object.

```js
const obj = {
  value:"something",
  insidefunc:function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
function test(){
  console.log(this);
}
obj.insidefunc(); //will log 'obj'
test(); //window object
```

#### Hositing:

You can use `test` before the line its declared but `obj.test` will only be accessed after the line its declared. Actually `function test()` show **hoisting**

```js
test(); //outer function  called

const obj = {}

obj.test() //"Uncaught TypeError: obj.test is not a function"

obj.test = function(){
  console.log("object method")
}

function test(){
   console.log("outer function  called");
}
```